# best approach to disable a button when .bad class is within a fieldset

Tags: jquery, forms

what would be the best approach for disabling a button if there is a div within a fieldset with a class of .bad?

HTML Example:

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="item>
    <label><span>First Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First" required>
    </label>
  </div>
  <!--adds .bad to parent when input doesn't validate -->
  <div class="item bad">
    <label><span>Last Name</span>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last" required>
    </label>
    <!-- .alert only present if doesn't validate -->
    <div class="alert">field is required</div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" class="prev button" value="Previous">
  <!-- "disabled" because .bad is present in parent container of Last Name -->
  <input type="button" class="next button" value="Next" disabled>
</fieldset>
```

The best approach and answer as been amended and applied to this example:
jQuery Example:

```
    // Bind to the 'change' event of the required input elements
$('input[required]').change(function () {
  // cache the value:
  var v = this.value;
  /* Look for the closest 'div.item',
    if the length of the trimmed value is equal to 0 we add 'bad' class,
    if it's not 0 we remove the 'bad' class:*/
  $(this).closest('div.item')[$.trim(v).length === 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('bad');
  /* we find the 'input' elements with 'type="button"',
    and set their disabled property according to whether,
    or not, there's a 'div.bad' contained within the 'fieldset' element: */
  $('input[type="button"].next').prop('disabled', function () {
    return $(this).closest('fieldset').find('div.bad').length > 0;
  });
  // We then trigger the 'change' event to disable the buttons if necessary:
}).change();
```

a working fiddle from David can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mwkAt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've already accepted another answer (at the time of my writing this answer), the way I'd probably approach this is as follows:

```
// Bind to the 'change' event of the required input elements:
$('input[required]').change(function(){
    // cache the value:
    var v = this.value;

    /* Look for the closest 'div.item',
       if the length of the trimmed value is equal to 0 we add 'bad' class,
       if it's not 0 we remove the 'bad' class:
    */
    $(this).closest('div.item')[$.trim(v).length === 0 ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('bad');

    /* we find the 'input' elements with 'type="button"',
       and set their disabled property according to whether,
       or not, there's a 'div.bad' contained within the 'fieldset' element:
    */
    $('input[type="button"].next').prop('disabled', function(){
        return $(this).closest('fieldset').find('div.bad').length > 0;
    });
// We then trigger the 'change' event to disable the buttons if necessary:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mwkAt/).

References:

- [Attribute-equals (`[attribute="value"]` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [Has-attribute (`[attribute]`)](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/).
- [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I must say, this works flawlessly. and the references to boot. I got the other option working, but it's messy with my adjustments included. I must update the best answer here on account of it truly being a better answer. 

Thanks

Comment: One more questions, made a new question for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338134/ignoring-other-options-when-validating

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
function check(){
        if($('fieldset .bad').length){
          $('#submit_butn_ID').attr('disabled',true)
        }
}
    $('#myform_ID').change(check())
```

or just

```
check()
```

how this wroks .:

1- we listen for changes in the form .

2- if there is any `.bad` in any field set then we add the attribute disabled to the button

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, but I'll keep fiddling with it to see if I can't get it to work. I'm assuming .length() is similar to .size() than?

Comment: post your fiddle please .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/ -- So it works, however, it's only after you begin typing into the first field. Which may just work if I stick an autofocus attribute to each fieldset's first field.

Comment: it's the way I have it setup, .bad isn't applied until you type in the wrong method, so I'll have to apply this to .alert and that should alleviate it. Thank you so much for your help!

just noticed you posted, I'll check it out