# ignoring other <options> when validating

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation

**I've refined this a little more:**

I'm now just trying to get the input & select fields to drop the attribute "required" if the corresponding option is not selected. (e.g. option value is = to div id). Currently, the fields that are set to display:none won't allow progress to the next fieldset since they have required fields, so if all fields from both options aren't filled in it won't proceed to the next fieldset. How can I get this ignore the fields that aren't displaying?

here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/darcher/aUKhN/26/

HTML

```
<form action="#" id="form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select an option</legend>
    <div class="item">
      <label><span>Option 1 or 2?</span>
        <select name="oneOrTwo" id="two-op" required>
          <option value="" disabled>&mdash; Select &mdash;
          <option value="one">Option 1
          <option value="two">Option 2
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div id="one" class="addInfo" style="display:none">
        <div class="item">
          <label><span>Option 1</span>
            <input type="text" name="op1" required>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="two" class="addInfo" style="display:none">
        <div class="item">
          <label><span>Option 2</span>
            <input type="text" name="op2" required>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="prev" class="prev" value="Previous">
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next" value="Next">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    ...
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
  $('#two-op').change(function () {
    $('.addInfo').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    var formElements = new Array("one", "two");
    for (i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).val() != formElements[i]) {
        $("#" + formElements[i]).children().find('input,select').each(function () {
          $(this).val('');
          $(this).removeAttr('required');
        });
      } else {
        $(this).attr('required', 'required');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**UPDATE: went with this approach**

```
   $(function () {
   $('#employment_status').change(function () {
       $('.addInfo').hide();
       $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        var formElements = new Array("emp","semp","ret","unemp","student");
        for(i=0; i < formElements.length; i++){
            if($(this).val()=="emp" ||$(this).val()=="semp" ) fieldSetNumber = 9;

            else fieldSetNumber = 3;
            if($(this).val()!=formElements[i]){
                $("#"+formElements[i]).children().find('input,select').each(function(){
                    $(this).parents("div").first().removeClass("good");
                    if($(this).is('input')) $(this).val('');
                    if($(this).is('select')) $(this).val('');
                });
            }
        }

   });
```

});

Comment: Can you make a shorter example and include it as a part of you question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can check whenever a element is visible with the [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector.

There is no need to add or delete the `require` attribute, you can easially check if it's visible. It will be ignored when it is hidden:

```
$('.addInfo:visible').find('input[type=text]').each(function()
{
   if($(this).val() == "")
   {
       if($(this).attr('required'))
       {
          alert('input field ' + $(this).attr('name') + ' is required!');
       }
    }
}
```

What i first check is if the parent element(`.addInfo`) is visible. Then i'll find the child input element. *again, this is only when the input field is visible*.

Now for every visible input i check if it has the attribute `required`. If so, it checks if the value has been filled in and will alert a message when that is not the case.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/aukHn/1/)**

**Note option 3**
Option 3 does not have the attribute `required`. This is to show you when a input element doesn't have the attribute `required` it *may* be blank.

Now all is good when nothing happens :)

Comment: We ended up doing things a little differently, each fieldset has a class now, class="f_3" where the number is the required fields (in this case 3), when a <select> is selected, it adds fields, but also appends the class name with the new amount of fields (e.g. from f_3 to f_9) if it added 6 more field, etc. etc. I do like your approach and since you took the time to bring this back I'll chalk you off as the answer for giving me a great approach to dig into in the future. 

I'll be updating many things to pseudo elements (e.g. :valid, :visible) in the future. So thanks for the good insight.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the validation per field when the user triggers the first `<select>`.
This can be done with a listener on the first `<select>` on `change`.
In your specific case :
`$('#empStatus').on('change', function() {
//init validation on fields you want
});`

In this event handler, you can approach fields in 2 ways.

- General fields
- Choice specific fields (or dynamic fields)

Obviously, fields that are not shown, should not be validated.

Comment: Updated code above, I tried using the change function to strip required but have come up short.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of what you wanted...

http://jsfiddle.net/9Q8R7/1/

code below

```
var t, cc=0, sp=$("<span class='err'>required</span>");

$('#btn').click(function(){
    if(!cc) return;
    var tt= true;
    $('#'+cc).children('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==''){tt= 0; return tt;}
    });
    if(tt) $('#f').submit();
});

$('#c').change(function(){
    cc=$(this).val();
    $('#f>fieldset').hide().filter("#"+cc).show();
});

$('input').on('blur',function(){
    t=$(this);
    if(t.val()=='') t.after(sp); 
    else t.next('.err').remove(); 
});
```

It lays out the principle and you can expand on it...but now you know what to do.

Comment: Couldn't get this to act how I needed it to. But appreciate the example.